# Why data is not deleting Laravel 5.3?

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to delete data from data information, but it is not deleting. is there any solution ? The deleting button is just below the edit button. And the destroy function is in the infoController.php

**Index.blade.php**

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>All userinfo</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row col-md-6 col-md-offset-2 custyle">

    <table class="table table-striped custab">
    <thead>
    <a href="userinfo/create" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs pull-right"><b>+</b> Add new categories</a>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Email</th>
            <th>Age</th>
            <th>Hometown</th>
            <th class="text-center">Action</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    @foreach($alldata as $data)

            <tr>
                <td>{{ $data -> id }}</td>
                <td>{{ $data -> name }}</td>
                <td>{{ $data -> email }}</td>
                <td>{{ $data -> age }}</td>
                <td>{{ $data -> hometown }}</td>

                <td class="text-center"><a class='btn btn-info btn-xs' style="margin-bottom:5px" href="{{route('userinfo.edit',$data->id)}}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span> Edit</a> 

                <a href="{{route('userinfo.destroy',$data->id)}}" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span> Delete</a></td>
            </tr>

           @endforeach

    </table>

  {!! $alldata -> render(); !!}

    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

**infoController.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Requests;

use App\infomodel;

class infoController extends Controller
{

 public function index()

 {


   $alldata = infomodel::paginate(4);

   return view('userinfo.index', compact('alldata'));


 }


 public function create()

 {


return view('userinfo.create');


 }


 public function store(Request $request)

 {

    $input = $request->all();

    infomodel:: create($input);

    return redirect('userinfo');


 }

 public function show ()

 {


 }


 public function edit($id)
 {


  $updateinfo = infomodel::findorfail($id);

  return view('userinfo.edit', compact('updateinfo'));



 }


 public function update(Request $request, $id)

 {

     $input = $request -> all();

     $data = infomodel::findorfail($id);

     $data -> update($input);

     return redirect('userinfo');



 }



 public function destroy ($id)

 {

     $data = infomodel::findorfail($id);

     $data -> delete();

     return redirect('userinfo');

 }




}
```

**Routes/web.php**

```
<?php


Route::resource('userinfo','infoController');


Route::get('/solid', function () {
    return view('solid.index');
});
```

Comment: What is happening? Do you get any errors? Does the `destroy()` method even get called?

Comment: You're calling a `POST` route with `GET`. You should get a `Method not allowed` Exception, right!?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're using [resource controller](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/controllers#resource-controllers), so you'll need to use `Delete` method, for example:

```
{!! Form::open(['method' => 'Delete', 'route' => ['someroute.destroy', $id]) !!}
    <button type="submit">Delete</button>
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

Or, you should use additional `Get` route:

```
Route::get('delete/{id}', 'MyController@deleteInfo');
```